# A DFT-based phasor estimation

Tags: fourier, digital-filter

I have the sample set of ideal and real secondary current during CT saturation, need to apply the DFT analysis to samples and estimate the fundamental phasor (magnitude and phase angle) of samples ([something like this](https://ibb.co/X3fybZR)).

I am far from digital signal processing but I suppose the main idea is to perform computation at each sample \$m\$ on the basis of \$N\$ historical samples.
I've been trying to apply following expressions:
$$I_{k}(m)=\sqrt{I_{RE}^2(m)+I_{IM}^2(m)}$$
$$\varphi(m)=\arctan\lgroup\frac{I_{IM}(m)}{I_{RE}(m)}\rgroup$$
$$I_{RE}(m)=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}i(m-n)\cdot \cos\lgroup\frac{2\pi k n}{N}\rgroup$$
$$I_{IM}(m)=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}i(m-n)\cdot \sin\lgroup\frac{2\pi k n}{N}\rgroup$$
where:
\$m\$ is the current sample
\$n\$ is the sample number in a cycle (window)
\$k\$ is the harmonic number
\$I_{k}(m)\$ is the output sample for harmonic \$k\$
\$i(m-n)\$ is the input sample set (stored samples)
\$N\$ is the number of samples in cycle (window)

Here is my c# code:

```
private DFTsample[] FourierAnalysis(List<double> inputSamples, List<double> inputTime, int k)
    {
        DFTsample[] dFTsamples = new DFTsample[inputSamples.Count];

        for (int m = 0; m < inputSamples.Count; m++)
        {
            if (inputTime.ElementAt(m) < 0)
            {
                dFTsamples[m] = new DFTsample() { Abs = 0, Angle = 0, Re = 0, Im = 0 };

                continue;
            }

            if(inputTime.ElementAt(m) >= 0)
            {
                dFTsamples[m] = new DFTsample();

                double Re = 0;

                double Im = 0;

                for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                {
                    Re += 2 / N * inputSamples[m - n] * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * k * n / N);

                    Im += 2 / N * inputSamples[m - n] * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * k * n / N);
                }

                dFTsamples[m].Re = Re;

                dFTsamples[m].Im = Im;

                dFTsamples[m].Abs = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Re, 2) + Math.Pow(Im, 2));

                dFTsamples[m].Angle = Math.Atan2(Re, Im) * 180 / Math.PI; 

            }
        }

        return dFTsamples;
    }
```

[My result](https://ibb.co/6bBV0NX) doesn't seem right, something went wrong. I'd really appreciate if you'd let me know how to use the DFT and compute magnitude and phase angle of secondary current.

Comment: I’m noticing a lack of atan2() calls and only atan() instead

Comment: Thank you, Bryan! Fixed it

Comment: No worries. I’ll try to make a formal answer for this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

As we worked out in the comments together, the issue with the algorithm as implemented in C# was that the arctangent function atan() does not disambiguate between quandrants I/IV and III/II. Replacing this atan() call with a call to atan2() returns angles in all 4 quadrants. Anytime one is using arctangent functions to infer real angles (ie not simply using atan because the plot looks nice) I would recommend using atan2 - it's probably more correct.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

One of the ways I quickly infer this is a problem is when I see graphs with discontinuities around the +- 90 deg (pi/2) values, such as these:

[image: Question results snip]

Discontinuities would be expected normally around +-180 deg, 90 is suspect and calls for review.